# What's the meaning of Neo4j's 'Variable length relationships'?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the page
[Neo4j Cypher 3.3.1 MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/)

The section 'Variable length relationships' puzzled me.

The example:

`MATCH (martin { name: 'Charlie Sheen' })-[:ACTED_IN*1..3]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN movie.title`

Return 3 rows with a repetition of 'The American President'.

And if i change 3 to 2, return only one row of 'Wall Street'. Why is that? And what's the meaning of `minHops` and `maxHops` in the section?

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with the number of relationships allowed to be traversed in the pattern.

As an example, for a social network graph, this would represent matching to all your friends:

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:123})-[:FRIEND]-(friend)
```

This represents friend-of-a-friend:

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:123})-[:FRIEND]-()-[:FRIEND]-(friendOfFriend)
```

This is the same thing but with variable-length relationships, showing that you want to traverse a :FRIEND relationship twice.

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:123})-[:FRIEND*2]-(friendOfFriend)
```

We can set a minimum and a maximum number of hops:

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:123})-[:FRIEND*1..3]-(friend)
```

This will return all nodes that can be reached by traversing at least one :FRIEND relationship, and at most 3 :FRIEND relationships.

If we set 0 as a lower bound, then the starting node `me` will also be included in the results for `friend`

```
MATCH (me:Person{id:123})-[:FRIEND*0..3]-(friend)
```

As for the example in the documentation, if we changed that query to return the paths rather than just the end nodes:

```
MATCH path = (charlie:Person { name: 'Charlie Sheen' })-[:ACTED_IN*1..3]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN path
```

you would see that there is one path of length 1 that ends on the node for Wall Street, and there are two distinct paths of length 3 that end on The American President.

Answer (score -1):

it's the number of path, not the number of nodes.

1..3 means that 1 or 2 or 3 steps to another node that match (movie:Movie).